# How can I unittest an Enum's __init__ method?

Tags: python, unit-testing, enums

I'm struggling to unit test the `__init__` method on an enumeration I'm using. The difficulty is that I can't extend the enum (so can't implicitly call `__init__`). When I try to directly call it from my test it insists that the first parameter should be an instance of that enum. I can't do this, because I can't assume any of the enum's properties in advance.

With a contrived example of the problem, let's say I have an enum of even numbers:

```
class EvenNumbers(Enum):
   two = 2
   four = 4
```

I want to do some value checking so that no-one accidentally adds an odd number to this enum:

```
class EvenNumbers(Enum):
   two = 2
   four = 4

   def __init__(self, value):
      assert value % 2 == 0
```

Now I want to write a test to make sure that this works. Two approaches seem intuitive but don't work:

```
def test_approach_1():
    '''
    Try to extend the Enum with a bad value. This fails
    because I can't extend an Enum.
    '''

    class BadEnum(EvenNumbers):
        three = 3

def test_approach_2():
    '''
    Try to call the __init__ method directly. This fails
    because I need to supply an instance of the enum as
    the first parameter and I can't assume any values are
    available.
    '''

    EvenNumbers.__init__(None, 3)
```

How should I unit test my `__init__` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When testing an `Enum` that is a one-off (in other words, you only have one `Enum` class that is restricted to even numbers), then just test that `Enum`'s values:

```
for enum in EvenNumbers:
    self.assertTrue(enum.value % 2 == 0)
```

If you have behavior you want shared among many enumerations, or the behavior being tested has to do with the actual creation of the members, then make a base class with just the behavior (no members):

```
class EvenNumbers(Enum):
    def __init__(self, value):
        if value % 2 ! = 0:
            raise ValueError('%d is not an even number' % value)
    def double(self):
        return self.value * 2
```

and then you can create test enumerations:

```
class TestEvenEnum(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_bad_value(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            class NotEven(EvenNumbers):
                one = 1

    def test_good_value(self):
        class YesEven(EvenNumbers):
            two = 2
        self.assertEqual(YesEven.two.double(), 4)
```

Comment: Yes, just testing the Enum's values is one of those solutions which is obviously correct when shown. *Facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

The solution I'm currently working with is to put the value checking logic into an empty enum:

```
class EvenNumbersBase(Enum):
   def __init__(self, val): assert val % 2 == 0

class EvenNumbers(EvenNumbersBase):
   two = 2
   four = 4
```

This allows me to test that EvenNumbers inherits from EvenNumbersBase. I can subsequently try to extend EvenNumbersBase with different values to test the **init** method.

This feels like jumping through a few hoops. Can you suggest a better way?